# Disallow Default Servlet writing permissions

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7, servlet-3.0

There was an CVE from oracle.

CVE-2017-5664
Possibility of circumvention of security constraints

Severity - Important

In the error page mechanism in the Java servlet specification, when an error occurs and an error page is configured, the original request and response need to be transferred to the error page.

If the error page is static, the desired behavior is to provide the content file as if it were processing a GET regardless of the actual HTTP method. Tomcat's default servlet did not do this. Depending on the original request, there may be unexpected and undesirable results, such as replacing or deleting custom error pages, if the default servlet allows writing.

My Question:
(a)Where can i check whether existing default servlet allows writing or not? 
(b)Where can i disallow default servlet writing ?

Answer (score 0):

For Tomcat 7 its the `readOnly` flag described here https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/default-servlet.html